# Python method refactoring

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been struggling with this problem so I would appreciate your help!

My university task is to write this method:

```
def removeRedundant(clauses, setOfSupport):

    newClauses = set()
    for clause in clauses:
        if not clause.isRedundant(clauses):
            newClauses.add(clause)

    newSOS = set()
    for clause in setOfSupport:
        if not clause.isRedundant(setOfSupport):
            newSOS.add(clause)

    return newClauses, newSOS
```

in a different way which avoids these 2 for loops.
I am wondering if it is possible to merge these two loops in one or there is even some other way to replace them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Vallentin what? No. Almost certainly the assignment wants you do refractor the code to do a single pass in parallel over `clauses` and `setOfSupport`, so likely something like `itertools.izip_longest`

Comment: Are `clauses` and `setOfSupport` of the same length? If yes, the task is relatively easy to accomplish.

Comment: What does `isRedundant` do?

Comment: Improving working code is within the scope of [codereview.se]. Here, it's generally off topic as non-reusable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be able to get rid of all the loops, but it's possible to merge the two loops into one:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def removeRedundant(clauses, setOfSupport):
    newClauses, newSOS = set(), set()

    for clause, support in izip_longest(clauses, setOfSupport, fillvalue=None):
        if (clause is not None) and (not clause.isRedundant(clauses)):
            newClauses.add(clause)
        if (support is not None) and (not support.isRedundant(setOfSupport)):
            newSOS.add(support)

    return newClauses, newSOS
```